My fungal strain (ITS sequences) shows similarities with different species. How can I identify it?
I sequenced the ITS gene of my strain, but when I performed a BLAST without applying any filter, I couldn't easily identify it. My strain shows similarities with different species!

Welcome to SE Biology! It would be most helpful if you could show the actual data, like the % identity/similarity of your sequence against each species' sequence. Recall that you would expect BLAST to recover multiple species, because fungal species are related to one another by evolution. You would hope to find that one species has a higher similarity than another.
